# Image not uploading 2nd time - Something went wrong

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, frontend, image-upload

We are Providing `product personalization` feature [ users can upload image from product view page & buy the product].

here user can upload any number of images by clicking [upload image button here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com:81/custom-apple-iphone-4.html)

[image]

1) click **upload image** button = > click **+Upload new image** in pop up  = > upload image from local system = > click on "**Add Image**" , than again if we try same steps, we will get an errors as below , means **1st time its working fine, but 2nd time show error**.

[image]

**But only in Mozilla Firefox 2nd time also its working fine.**

**AjaxController.php**

```
public function addImageAction()
    {
        $response = array();
        if(isset($_FILES['new_image']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name']))) {
            $uploader = $this->setUpUploader();
            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'custom_product_preview' . DS . 'quote' . DS;
            try 
            {
                $uploader->save($path, preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z\d\.]/','_',$_FILES['new_image']['name']));
                $filename = $uploader->getUploadedFileName();

                $filename = $this->_convertToImg($filename);

                if(getimagesize($path.$filename)!==false)
                {
                    $response['src'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'custom_product_preview/quote/'.$filename;
                    $response['error'] = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    $response['error'] = Mage::helper('aitcg')->__('Image file is empty or corrupt');
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e)
            {
                $response['error'] = $e->getMessage();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            $response['error'] = Mage::helper('aitcg')->__('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
        }

        $this->_setBodyJson($response); 
    }
```

**System.log**

[image]

**Edit** : seems above system.log error is not related to this issue

**edit 2** : console

[image]

**Edit 3**

```
loaded : function(id) {
        var d, 
            i = $(id);
        if (i && i.contentDocument) {
            d = i.contentDocument;
        } else if (i && i.contentWindow) {
            d = i.contentWindow.document;
        } else {
            d = window.frames[id].document;
        }


        with($(this.file_id)) {
            disabled = false;
            value = "";
        }

        if (typeof(i.onComplete) == 'function') {
            eval('var el = ' + d.body.innerHTML + ';');
            i.onComplete( el );
            element = document.getElementById(id).parentNode;
            element.parentNode.removeChild(element);

        }
    }
```

Comment: Make sure You have set property permissions for your project. Eg. media and var have writing permisions

Comment: @KonradSiamro Thanks for informing, we will correct it.....

Comment: Np, If that helps ill make it as answer for other users ;)

Comment: @KonradSiamro no , sorry thats not the reason.....

Comment: can you check system logs? apache / nginx?

Comment: @KonradSiamro related to this issue, there is no errors in `system.log` , i wil check with server team if there is any niginx errors or not, but still i dont think its issue from server .....

Comment: i dont know which developer created mozilla firefox, that guy is really awesome, because its working fine in mozilla only......

Comment: I see. Are You sure that js for getting image is working property? If browser makes difference this may be a problem. Please check  browser console logs - using eg. firebug

Comment: @KonradSiamro i updated question with screenshot of console errors.... in console one  [link](http://stylebaby.com/aitcg/ajax/addImage/) display error....

Comment: @KonradSiamro there is no issue with image property, i am trying with valid images, if i upload `image1` & in 2nd time if i try to upload same image still it shows error.

Comment: Problem is with `if(isset($_FILES['new_image']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['new_image']['tmp_name'])))`. There is no info about image in $_FILES. What is happening in code after add image? It should be passed by ajax to controller or save in $_FILES

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52927/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-and-konrad-siamro).

Comment: @KonradSiamro Thanks buddy, with your suggestions only i solved the issue.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

adding below code to JS solved the issue....

```
if (d.location.href == "about:blank") {
            $(d).remove();
            return;
        }
```